# How to parse svn diff results?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, grep

Using `svn diff` with the `--summarize` flag returns something like the below.  How would we pass this to sed or grep to do the following:

1. Remove any lines that start with "D" (deleted files)
2. Remove the prefix of the "M", "A" or "MM" (or any other cases) along with the tab afterward.
3. Remove the URL path only leaving the filenames/folder.
4. Store in a file

Example:

```
D   https://localhost/example/test1.php
D   https://localhost/example/test2.php
M   https://localhost/example/test3.php
M   https://localhost/example/test4.php
A   https://localhost/example/test5.php
M   https://localhost/example/test6.php
A   https://localhost/example/test7.php
M   https://localhost/example/test8.php
M   https://localhost/example/test9.php
M   https://localhost/example/test10.php
A   https://localhost/example/test11.php
M   https://localhost/example/test12.php
M   https://localhost/example/test13.php
MM  https://localhost/example/test.php
M   https://localhost/test0.php
```

Would then become:

```
/example/test3.php
/example/test4.php
/example/test5.php
/example/test6.php
/example/test7.php
/example/test8.php
/example/test9.php
/example/test10.php
/example/test11.php
/example/test12.php
/example/test13.php
/example/test.php
/test0.php
```

Comment: Your output doesn't match your specification, it shouldn't include `test1.php` or `test2.php` as they start with `D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this with `sed`:

```
$ svn diff --summarize | sed -e '/^D/d' -e 's/.*host//'
/example/test3.php
/example/test4.php
/example/test5.php
/example/test6.php
/example/test7.php
/example/test8.php
/example/test9.php
/example/test10.php
/example/test11.php
/example/test12.php
/example/test13.php
/example/test.php
/test0.php

# Redirect output to file
$ svn diff --summarize | sed -e '/^D/d' -e 's/.*host//' > file
```

You need to [pipe](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=21) `|` the output of `svn` to `sed`. The first part `'/^D/d'` deletes all the lines starting with `D` and the second `s/.*host//` substitutes everything up to `host` with nothing, to store in to a file use [redirect](http://www.linux-tutorial.info/modules.php?name=MContent&pageid=21) `> file`.

Similar logic with `grep`:

```
$ svn diff --summarize | grep '^[^D]' file | grep -Po '(?<=host).*' > file
```

The first `grep` filters out the lines that start with `D` and the second uses [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) with `-Po` to display only the part of the line after `host`.